# JPA Mapping Query gives error

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am new in JPA so I made a small application. And in my app, I have a @Query like:

```
@Query("select a from T_RBM_OPSCREENS_APPLICATIONS a, T_SCR_APPS_OPS_ROLES b where a.id=b.app_id and b.role_id=?1")
```

When application starts running, it gives the error:

> Caused By: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
>   T_RBM_OPSCREENS_APPLICATIONS is not mapped [select a from
>   T_RBM_OPSCREENS_APPLICATIONS a, T_SCR_APPS_OPS_ROLES b where
>   a.id=b.app_id and b.role_id=?1]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:110)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:324)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3270)
>     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

But I did the Mapping like:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "T_RBM_OPSCREENS_APPLICATIONS", schema = "RBMCORE")
    public class Application implements Serializable{

        @Id

        @Column(name = "id")
        private int id;

        @Column(name = "s_appname", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private String name;
.
.
.
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JPQL/HQL queries use entities and their persistent fields/properties/associations. They don't use tables and columns.

Your query should be something like:

```
select a from Application a inner join a.roles role where role.id = ?1
```

Read [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. U are right about it, I saw the lines in the documentary, but the table above "T_SCR_APPS_OPS_ROLES" is not a model table so it has no model objects in my code. So the hql that u wrote was not completely right. Is there a way to use real table names with it?

Comment: No. The point of an ORM is to map relational tables to objects. If you don't do it, then use JDBC and SQL.